# How to load assembly files using Edge.js when hosting the app in iisnode

Tags: javascript, iisnode, edgejs

Is it possible to use edge.js with an application which is hosted on iisnode. A simple inline code like this-

```
var hello = edge.func(function () {
    /*
    async(input) => {
      return ".NET welcomes " + input.ToString();
    }
    */
});
```

works properly when the `server.js` file is handled using iisnode. But in case the edge proxy func is using an assembly file, we need to set EDGE env variables like `EDGE_USE_CORECLR` and `EDGE_APP_ROOT`. How do we set these variables in iisnode?